# React component does not react to mobx observable data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I am using **mobX** for my react native project. Please consider this store class:

```
class Birds {
    @observable listOne = [];
    @observable fetchingListOne = false;
    @observable fetchErrorOne = '';

    @action setListOne = () => {
        this.fetchingListOne = true;
        api.getList()
            .then((data) => {
                this.listOne.replace(data);
                this.fetchingListOne = false;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.fetchingListOne = false;
                this.fetchErrorOne = error;
            });
    };
}
```

And this the react component:

```
@inject('BirdStore') @observer
export default class Flat extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.BirdStore.setListOne();
    }

    _renderHeader = () => {
        return <Text style={styles.listHeaderText}>
            Hello {this.props.BirdStore.listOne.length} is {this.props.BirdStore.fetchingListOne.toString()}
            </Text>;
    };

    _renderItem = ({item}) => {
        return <Text style={styles.item}>{item.name}</Text>
    };

    _renderFooter = () => {
        if (this.props.BirdStore.fetchingListOne) {
            return <ActivityIndicator/>
        }
        else {
            return null
        }
    };

    render() {
        const dataSource = this.props.BirdStore.listOne.slice();

        return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text>Fetching: {this.props.BirdStore.fetchingListOne.toString()}</Text>
                    <FlatList
                        style={styles.listContainer}
                        ListHeaderComponent={this._renderHeader}
                        data={dataSource}
                        renderItem={this._renderItem}
                        keyExtractor={(item, i) => item.id}
                        ListFooterComponent={this._renderFooter}
                    />
                </View>
        )
    }
}
```

From above it looks to me that:

1. When the `Flat` component mounts, it call the method of the store `setListOne()`.
2. `setListOne()` sets `fetchingListOne` to true and makes an api call.
3. On the component side, when the `fetchingListOne` is true, the *ActivityIndicator* displays, and in the *ListHeaderComponent* it should display true.
4. On the store side, after successful/unsuccessful response, it sets `fetchingListOne` to false.
5. Finally on the component side, because `fetchingListOne` is set to false, *ActivityIndicator* should not display and in the *ListHeaderComponent* it should display false.

However, this is not what's happening. Here when the `setListOne()` method is called, after it sets the `fetchingListOne` to true, the component does not react to the changes made after api call. And the *ActivityIndicator* keeps displaying and in *ListHeaderComponent* its displaying true.

What am I doing wrong here? Could you please help me. Thank you

**Update**

I have added a Text component before the FlatList. Adding a Text component or console logging inside the component class's render method does makes the FlatList react to the changes. I don't know why this is happening though.

Comment: Could you try and use `mobx.useStrict()` to see if it fixes your issue? This means using getters and setters for your observable values, especially `fetchingListOne`

Comment: @ChristopherChiche I tried placing `mobx.useStrict(true)` in the store.js where the **Birds** class is present. But that gave me an error: *...Please wrap the code in an `action` if this change is intended. Tried to modify: Birds@2.listOne]*. So I placed `useStrict();` in the `@action setListOne`. It does not throw any errors, but it has the same problem; the **FlatList** component does not react to that changes like they should be.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you are running into here most probably, is that although `Flat` is an `observer` component, `FlatList` is not (it's an built-in component after all). In this setup `_renderFooter` and the others are part are rendered by `render` of `FlatList`, but not of `FlatList`. Hence they are not part of the lifecycle of Flat, but of FlatList and as such are not tracked by Mobx

There are two ways to fix this, both pretty simple:

1) declare `_renderItem` as observer component:

```
_renderItem = observer(({item}) =>
    <Text style={styles.item}>{item.name}</Text>
);
```

2) use an inline anonymous `Observer` component:

```
_renderItem = ({item}) => 
    <Observer>{
        () => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.name}</Text>}
    </Observer>
```

Comment: Yes, I think that's what the problem is because I have added a **Text** component above the FlatList and it does react to the changes, *also, this makes the whole FlatList work perfectly* (updated the code please have look at Class's render method). Anyways, the first method gives an error, [TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function]. And the second method basically does the same thing; it does render all the list after fetching.